# Python 2.7 print with unintentional new lines

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, newline, line-breaks

still fairly new to Python..

I'm iterating through a text file:

```
0x000B000A
0x000B000B
0x000B000C
```

And appending each line to a base url and here is the specific part of the code which I'm having an issue with:

```
def ProcessID(id):
  url = baseUrl + "/" + id + "/" + type + "-" + id + "-" + version + "." + extension
  print "Processing: " + url

for line in inputFile:
      ProcessID(line)
```

The problem is that any lines ending with `A` or `B` adds a line break in the print command:

```
Processing: http://example.com/0x000B000A
/LST3-0x000B000A
-000000.ext
Processing: http://example.com/0x000B000B
/LST3-0x000B000B
-000000.ext
Processing: http://example.com/0x000B000C/LST3-0x000B000C-000000.ext
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this something to do with how Python is interpreting the string (i.e. in Unicode 0A, 0B)?

Thanks,
PJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When iterating over lines in a file like that, the lines will still contain the final linebreak `'\n'` (except the last line if there is no empty line after that). It is easiest just to strip them off:

```
for line in inputFile:
      ProcessID(line.strip())
      # OR: if you want to be more explicit and keep all other white space
      ProcessID(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: Ah! Excellent, thank you. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: can't we use `replace` as well?

Comment: @VanPeer Sure, since a line in this context can contain only one line break. But I'd go with `strip` because it is more specific (and does not have to search through the entire line).

Answer (score 0):

You’re inserting the whole line, with its break. You should remove it from each line. You can do `line.replace("\n", "")`